# IP addresses: Likelihood of non-reserved address falling outside of 100.*?

Tags: dns, ip, ip-address, ipv4

One of the reserved IP address ranges as define [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses) is:

**Block**
100.64.0.0/10

**Range**
100.64.0.0 –
100.127.255.255

I'm trying to construct a regex that will capture any address in this range, but I don't see a way to do it without specifying every possible value for the second 8 bits.

If I just left my regex as "any IP address beginning with 100.", would that suffice? Or to put it another way, are there any **non**-reserved address that beginning with 100 but which **don't** fall within 100.64.0.0 –
100.127.255.255?

Comment: If you're using Perl you can use something like `(\d+)(??{ $^N>64 && $^N<128 ? '' : '(?!)' })` to check the second triplet. But regexps are definitely the wrong tool for this, and I suggest you use something else instead to save your own sanity. And since the IPv4 space is close to exhausted, the likelihood that you'll get an address starting with 100 but outside the range is significant.

Comment: A regex is indeed the wrong tool. Easier to convert the address to a number or string (e.g. inet_pton) so that you can do a normal range check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question "Likelihood of non-reserved address falling outside of 100.*?": 100%

See for example http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-100-0-0-0-1 and http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-100-48-0-0-1. Those are just two examples of some huge ISPs using space from `100.0.0.0/8`.